# Связь с другим предложением при помощи формы слова

Tags: синтаксис

> (1) Чтобы справляться со своими обязанностями, человек должен обладать
>   благородной душой, полной лучших качеств. (2) Но почему, даже обладая
>   добродетельными качествами, человек совершает безнравственные
>   поступки?

Второе предложение связано с первым при помощи *союза*, *форм слова* и *контекстных синонимов*.

Как я понимаю, союз здесь *даже*, контекстный синоним --  *добродетельные качества*. Но где здесь *форма слова*? Можете показать связь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Союз для связи - это НО (ДАЖЕ - частица).

Формы слова:  обладать, обладая.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже подметили, союз, связывающий предложения, это НО. Формы слова здесь не столько "обладать, обладая", сколько "качеств-качествами", потому что связь с помощью формы слова — это то же самое слово, но с другим окончанием (в другом падеже, числе), а здесь именно это и есть — просто разное окончание. Контекстные синонимы — это "лучшие качества — благородные качества", так как это по сути одно и то же, то есть те качества, которые благородные, они самые лучшие.